# How to remove an EIP with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-nat-gateway

I deleted `aws_eip` resources and it's corresponding `aws_nat_gateway` `allocation_id` reference in terraform code. `terraform plan` correctly shows these resources being destroyed, however `terraform apply` results in the following error:

```
│ Error: disassociating EC2 EIP (eipassoc-02d1f94af0eb9ef67): AuthFailure: You do not have permission to access the specified resource.
│   status code: 400, request id: ...
```

The AWS access key I'm using has full administrator access, with the following IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

so what is preventing these resources from being destroyed?

Comment: Perhaps you are part of a group with restricted access? Or maybe you're part of a locked down AWS organization?